# Test if application is thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading

I have simple application which simulates money transfer from one account to another. I want to write a test that will show that it is not thread safe.

There is a possibility that threads will go in such way that transfer will be done twice. Two threads scenario:

- acc1 = 1000$
- acc2 = 0$
- transfer 600$

  1. T1: get acc1 balance (1000)
  2. T2: get acc1 balance (1000)
  3. T1: subtract 600$ from account1 (400)
  4. T2: subtract 600$ from account2 (400)
  5. T1: increase acc2 by 600$ (600)
  6. T2: increase acc2 by 600$ (1200)

Currently my application doesn't support multithreading and it should fail, that is fine for me now. I am able to simulate error with debugger. However when I do thread test it's always succesful. I tried with different number of threads, sleeps, callabletasks

```
@Test
    public void testTransfer() throws AccountNotFoundException, NotEnoughMoneyException, InterruptedException {
        Callable<Boolean> callableTask = () -> {
            try {
                moneyTransferService.transferMoney(ACCOUNT_NO_1, ACCOUNT_NO_2, TRANSFER_AMOUNT);
                return true;
            } catch (AccountNotFoundException | NotEnoughMoneyException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        };

        List<Callable<Boolean>> callableTasks = new ArrayList<>();
        int transferTries = 2;
        for(int i = 0; i <= transferTries; i++) {
            callableTasks.add(callableTask);
        }

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        executorService.invokeAll(callableTasks);

        Assert.assertEquals(ACCOUNT_BALANCE_1.subtract(TRANSFER_AMOUNT), accountRepository.getByAccountNumber(ACCOUNT_NO_1).get().getBalance());
        Assert.assertEquals(ACCOUNT_BALANCE_2.add(TRANSFER_AMOUNT), accountRepository.getByAccountNumber(ACCOUNT_NO_2).get().getBalance());
    }
```

Here's code for money transfer:

```
public void transferMoney(String accountFrom, String accountTo, BigDecimal amount) throws AccountNotFoundException, NotEnoughMoneyException {
        Account fromAccount = getAccountByNumber(accountFrom);
        Account toAccount = getAccountByNumber(accountTo);

        if (isBalanceSufficient(amount, fromAccount)) {

            //TODO this should be thread safe and transactional
            BigDecimal fromNewAmount = fromAccount.getBalance().subtract(amount);
            fromAccount.setBalance(fromNewAmount);

            // it's possible to fail junits with sleep but I dont want it in code obviously
//          Random random = new Random();
//          try {
//              Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(100));
//          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//              e.printStackTrace();
//          }

            BigDecimal toNewAmount = toAccount.getBalance().add(amount);
            toAccount.setBalance(toNewAmount);

        } else {
            throw new NotEnoughMoneyException("Balance on account: " + fromAccount.getNumber() + " is not sufficient to transfer: " + amount);//TODO add currency
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without providing the source code, it's hard to tell how to cause some concurrency problem.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj added

Comment: Re, "I want to write a test that will show that it is not thread safe." Attempts to prove (or disprove) the thread safety of any piece of code by testing generally are futile. The problem is, for even a small piece of code, there can be an overwhelming number of different ways in which the stores and loads that the different threads perform on memory can be interleaved. Whatever compiler you use, whatever operating system and hardware platform you test on, chances are, the instructions will be interleaved differently if you try it on any other system, any other compiler, maybe any other day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of multi-threading. As a comment points out, it's going to be very hard to determine a way of proving anything without the full source code.

But also it can be hard to provoke threading errors. The first rule of multi-threading is you can't prove (or easily disprove) code is thread-safe by exercise (e.g. unit) testing.

Unsafe code may execute a billion times without error. On some platforms it may in fact be thread-safe but on others fail consistently. The idea that all Java code behaves the same on all platforms goes out of the window when you start using threads.

This code (invented content of your class) isn't guaranteed thread-safe in Java:

```
balance+=transaction;
```

But it's also such a small piece of code it potentially could be safe on some platforms or simply so fast it runs billions of times without error.

```
int temp=balance;
Thread.sleep(1000);
balance=temp+transaction;
```

Has a good chance of eventually failing on most platforms. **But so what?**
It proves nothing about the original line of code and sometimes introducing delays masks issues particularly elsewhere.

The only way to verify or invalidate multi-threaded code is static analysis and a good knowledge of the language guarantees.

You can try running at high-load with (say) twice as many threads as your platform can actually run in parallel and making some guesses about the underlying code you've got a good chance of provoking a problem. But some errors may only occur at low load or any load inbetween.

Remember if you modify the code re-test and it works *you've proved nothing*. I'm not saying you shouldn't run such tests as a final check.

But never imagine unit-tests help demonstrate reliability for multi-threading in a way they help with single-threaded. That's particularly because different platforms may have different configurations (e.g. number of processes, cache levels, cores) and experience different levels of load.

Answer (score 1):

If all it takes is to introduce timeout than mock `getAccountByNumber` in the test e.g. by using [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) and make mock `Account.setBalance()` take X seconds.

You can take a look at [jcstress](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jcstress/) framework for writing concurrent tests. One example [here](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#intro-jcstress).

> The Java Concurrency Stress tests (jcstress) is an experimental harness and a suite of tests to aid the research in the correctness of concurrency support in the JVM, class libraries, and hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You might stub `getAccountByNumber(accountFrom)` and implement some "wait code" in the `getBalance()` code only for your test.

Anyway, I suggest you to move your service code to your business object, i.e. add method `Account#transferTo(Account target, BigDecimal amount)`.

Then you can simply mark this method as `synchronized` or do some dedicated synchronization.

Going even further you could create a `public synchronized void accept(BigDecimal amount)`, too. Thus marking each balance-changing method synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

I have used threadtester which is great tool for my task:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapdb</groupId>
        <artifactId>thread-weaver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.mapdb</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```